# Are having the D&D 4e books and errata sufficient to replace a subscription?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm considering playing around with D&D 4e again.  I last ran it in 2012 and had a DDI subscription to get the latest rules, monsters, etc.  I'm not really interested in subscribing to the online tools again.

For material in published books, is the errata as complete as the online tools?  I know I won't have access to online-only stuff, but will players who have a subscription have a different version of the print stuff than I will from the print material plus errata?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It is sufficient to have access to the books and errata.

At its best the online material is reprints of what is in the books with the errata applied, at worst it has typos or is still the original book text without the errata applied. That said, it's usually correct and the most up to date it can be.

So yeah, if you have the books you need, then the errata is sufficient to replace the compendium, character builder and monster builder. The only thing you won't have access to is the materials in subscription only articles for Dungeon and Dragon magazines.

But by and large, you should have the same information as players with a DDI sub.

Comment: In fact, you'd have slightly _more_: DDI is pretty much a "just the facts" approach, and doesn't include things like setting information.

Comment: DDI also tends to lag by about a month (well, it did when I was using it). Also, I'd highly recommend that one of the books you should own is the Rules Compendium.

Comment: @Ellesedil considering 4e is pretty much finished (it's been about 2 years since the latest errata has come out, and about that long since a new book was published, and Dungeon and Dragon both went on hiatus in January), that's not an issue at this point.